# Do not see the controller and model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view, model, asp.net-mvc-areas

in views/jump/index have problem.

first rows:

```
@model IEnumerable<WhislaMvc.Areas.Admin.Models.Jump>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
```

@model and ViewBaf - do not see.
I take error:

> compilation Error Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'model'
>   does not exist in the current context Compiler Error Message: CS0103:
>   The name 'ViewBug' does not exist in the current context

[image]

**Update:**
I comment model and ViewBag

```
@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
```

**Html not have method ActionLink why????**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question description, it shows that, I think you are using `Asp.Net MVC 2` and you just tried to use the `functionality of Asp.Net MVC 3.`

**`ViewBag`** comes with `Asp.Net MVC 3 (It's feature of Asp.Mvc 3)`

There are few suggestions that you can try to avoid compilation error.

1. Install `Asp.Net MVC 3` (Install .`Net Framework 4 prior`)
2. `Change your project property.` (Right Click Web Project -> click
       'Properties' -> Application tab -> Target Framework -> Change to
       .NET Framework 4

**Check and Change your web.config as below:**

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
            <assemblies>
                <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
                <add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
                <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
                <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
                <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
                <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
            </assemblies>
        </compilation>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

All the problems were with the configuration of Web.Config in Area / Admin / Views

WebConfig I get from Views/Web.Config/ is standart.

Comment: This should be a comment, not and "Answer".

Comment: @DaveShaw - to be fair it is the OP answering his own question. Deniska - it would be useful if you could expand your answer, and remember to mark as accepted when able to.